# Episerver Forms 3.0.0.0

Tags: episerver

How do I prevent post if validation on my formset failed?
If there is a missing value on any required field I dont want the information to get erased if I press the send button ("SKICKA").

[image: Image of the form]

*I apologize for the mixed language in the picture.*

Answer (score 1):

In your **Edit mode for Epi form** if you scroll down you should be able to see all the fields listed in a list called **Form elements**
e.g. your Namn field, click that in the Form elements and edit it. You will see a list of **Validators** which you can choose from. Adding a required or any other suitable validation will prevent the form from posting if there were no text proveded.

Comment: I have validators on each required field, however it still performs a post which fails because i didnt fill each required field. So the page reloads and all my fields are empty afterwards. Is this happening for you?

Comment: @Dujskan it does not do any post if i do not fill in all the required fields. Do you get any console error or something?
I have disabled now the javascript from the chrome-devtool and only then the form is submitted but if fails and says failed to validate required field or something similar.